# P0017 after oil change

Tags: oil-change, camshaft

I have a 07 Cadillac CTS.  I got my oil changed on Saturday at a Valvoline oil change shop, didn't drive Sunday, then on Monday my check engine light came on and the car now accelerates slowly.  The fault code is P0017, which is Camshaft Position Correlation (Bank 1 Sensor B).  The timing seems suspicious, could they have done something incorrect during the oil change to have caused this problem?

EDIT:
After about an hour of driving, the engine began accelerating normally.  I disconnected the battery today to reset the Check Engine Light and when turning back on the light stays off.  My best guess is that after the oil change, the oil pressure was low for some reason which caused the timing to get off but luckily it was able to correct itself

Comment: Welcome to the site. There is no way for us to know what they did while they had your car. I would suggest you check all the connections under the hood. If one was disconnected (intentional or otherwise) it could cause a code. Obviously, start looking in the vicinity of the Cam Position Sensor.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I was primarily wondering if improper oil level/viscosity or a problem with the oil filter could cause it.  I didn't even consider that it could have been disconnected, that's certainly something easy to check.

Comment: I said what I did about it being disconnected because I have had oil techs inadvertently dislodge plugs while trying to check or change a difficult air filter. Just a simple oil change won't do it, but many places perform a multi-point check for other things they can offer to replace; air filter, wiper blades, etc.

Comment: What engine does the car have?  Have you confirmed that the oil level is correct?  This technically could be caused by the oil (or lack thereof).

Comment: I agree with Zshoulders here, oil level/viscosity is the number one cause of these cam correlation codes. Next being the solenoid and lastly timing chains or actuators. If an actuator or sensor were unplugged you'd have sensor or solenoid circuit codes.

Answer (score -1):

I have an MB w204 from 2011 and had the same error code.
I replaced the cam and crankshaft position sensors, checked the solenoids, the chain and vacuum lines but the problem still persisted when the engine was at max temperature.
The shop did a short analysis and told me it was the chain and the camshaft that was damaged. Since I already replaced the chain and the camshafts 2 years ago, I believed this was nonsense and must be something else.
The engine choke itself when idle, vibrated alot and missfired.
After oil and oilfilter replacement, the problem was solved.
This is something I should have thought of since the car has been mostly standing still for the last year and caused the oil to loose its lubricating properties which in turn caused the oil not to dissipate the eat and lubricate the timing chain properly. I hope this may solve p0017 error code for a concerned car owner.